# How to refactor from static methods to Dependency Injection using MS.DI and .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am in the process of migrating a project from .Net Framework to .Net Core. In the existing project we have a utility class with a few functions like below:

```
public static class BudgetUtilities
{
    public static decimal CalculateBudgetRemaining(string fiscalYear = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fiscalYear))
            fiscalYear = DateTime.Now.GetFiscalYear().ToString();

        using (AppContext _context = new AppContext())
        {
            FiscalYearBudget currentBudget = _context.FiscalYearBudgets.Find(fiscalYear);

            return currentBudget.BudgetAllocation - currentBudget.ExpenditureToDate;
        }
    }

    // other functions removed for brevity
}
```

I can then reference it anywhere else using `BudgetUtilities.CalculateBudgetRemaining()`. Very simple and straightforward.

When migrating this function to .Net Core I need to use Dependency Injection so I have amended the class by removing the static modifier (since static constructors cannot have parameters) and injecting the AppContext into the constructor:

```
public class BudgetUtilities
{
    private readonly AppContext _context;

    public BudgetUtilities(AppContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public decimal CalculateBudgetRemaining(string financialYear = null)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fiscalYear))
            fiscalYear = DateTime.Now.GetFiscalYear().ToString();

        FiscalYearBudget currentBudget = _context.FiscalYearBudgets.Find(fiscalYear);

        return currentBudget.BudgetAllocation - currentBudget.ExpenditureToDate;
    }
}
```

I then tried to call my code by doing the following:

```
BudgetUtilities utils = new BudgetUtilities();
decimal remaining = utils.CalculateBudgetRemaining();
```

But I cannot make a new instance of BudgetUtilities without providing an AppContext in the constructor which makes sense. Every method in this application is at some point initiated by a controller action, and I know that `DbContext`s are supposed to be short lived, so I assume passing the context the whole way down to this BudgetUtilities class from the initial controller is a bad idea.

The only other option I can see is to keep going back up the call stack from where `CalculateBudgetRemaining()` is referenced and keep adding in constructor injections until I get to a controller but this is not the only class I will have to inject like this so my constructors further up the chain are going to be really bloated and this will make my `ConfigureServices()` method bloated too.

I'm sure there's a simple way to do this but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manually create a new `BudgetUtilities` instance, that type should also be registered with the DI Framework, preferably interfaced:

```
public interface IBudgetUtilities
{
    decimal CalculateBudgetRemaining(string financialYear);
}

public class BudgetUtilities : IBudgetUtilities
```

Then in Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddScoped<IBudgetUtilities, BudgetUtilities>();
}
```

Then it can be injected into any class that needs it, such as a controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBudgetUtilities _utils;

    public YourController(IBudgetUtilities utils)
    {
        _utils = utils;
    }

    public ActionResult YourMethod()
    {
        //...
        decimal remaining = _utils.CalculateBudgetRemaining();
    }
}
```

By default, registered `DbContexts` have a scoped lifetime, which means a single instance is used for the entirety of a HTTP request.

Comment: I get that, but I have a lot of other utility classes that I would have to reference in this way as well. Just seems Like I would be bloating my Controller constructor with like 15 parameters and bloating my ConfigureServices() method too.

Comment: @TridentTrue Maybe read [this](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: A lot of refactoring in my future then.